# Dynamically Shrinking Size of An iFrame Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame window on the page, the content inside of the iFrame ether shrinks or grows larger in height depending of different AJAX calls. 
I want to dynamically re-size height of an iframe window based on the height of iframe's content
My code:

```
var $iFrame = $('#iFrameWindow');
var lastHeight;

setInterval(function () {
    if ($iFrame.contents().height() != lastHeight) {
        $iFrame.css({
            height: $iFrame.contents().height() + 'px'
        });

        lastHeight = $iFrame.contents().height();            
    }
}, 200);
```

It works if iFrame's content grows larger then my iFrame window automatically gets re-sized to a larger height, but if iFrame's content shrinks in height $iFrame.contents().height() does not detect that change and shows old, larger and incorrect height for the iFrame's content.

How do I also make my iFrame to dynamically shrink if height if the iFrame changes to smaller height?

Comment: I would suggest you look into messages http://viget.com/extend/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes.  I had to do something similar, and this was the solution

Comment: Jason, your article is talking about dealing with cross domain iFrame communication issue, I don't have that issue, my iFrame is on the same domain.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the concept is the same.